# How can I shorten the function call to retrieve a certain line matching some regexp string only

Tags: regex, powershell, match, ghci, cabal-install

In my profile file I have a definition for running sandboxed `ghci` instances like:

```
function sandbox-ghci {
  $regex = '^package-db: (.*)$'
  $db = Get-Content .\cabal.sandbox.config | foreach { if($_ -match $regex) { %{$_ -replace $regex, '${1}'} } }
  Start-Process -FilePath ghci.exe -ArgumentList "-no-user-package-db -package-db $db $args"
}

Set-Alias -Name ghci -Value sandbox-ghci
```

How could I shorten especially the line which retrieves the certain regex-matching line from the `.\cabal.sandbox.config` file:

```
$db = Get-Content .\cabal.sandbox.config | foreach { if($_ -match $regex) { %{$_ -replace $regex, '${1}'} } }
```

EDIT:

Came up with (can remove the now redundant `$regex` declaration than) as one attempt:

```
$db = Select-String -Path .\cabal.sandbox.config '^package-db: (.*)$' | % {$_.Matches} | % {$_.Groups[1].Value}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use `-match` as an array operator and then trim the "package".

```
$db = (Get-Content .\cabal.sandbox.config) -match $regex -replace "package-db: "
```

It feels like cheating with the extra `-replace` but I think this gets the result you are looking for. Continue reading and I like more where this goes.

**Use a lookbehind**

This is *closer* to what I was hoping for. However is is possible for this to return an array if there is more than one line that matches the `$regex`. If that is a concern you could add a `Select-Object -First 1` just in case.

```
$regex = '(?<=package-db: ).*'
$db = Get-Content .\cabal.sandbox.config | Where-Object{$_ -match $regex} | ForEach-Object{$Matches[0]}
```

Using a `Where-Object` is functionally the same as what you were trying to do with you `foreach` and `if`. We just use the `$Matches[0]` to get the result back.

Using the same regex as above a `Select-String` solution could also work

```
$db = (Get-Content .\cabal.sandbox.config | Select-String -Pattern $regex).Matches.Value
```

and like Arco was leading me too you dont really need to waste time with `Get-Content`

```
$db = (Select-String .\cabal.sandbox.config -Pattern $regex).Matches.Value
```

**PowerShell 2.0 or lower**

Having a sneaky suspicion that your version is 2.0 or something. I think the dot notation does not work in 2.0 the way I have it. I offer this then as a compromise

```
$db = Select-String .\cabal.sandbox.config -Pattern $regex | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
```

Comment: your answer is correct and `$db` contains what I wanted as in my original code what I'm asking for is an expression with only one `"package-db: "` occurence in it.

Comment: Do you need to call  `Get-Content` at all in your `Select-String` version?

Comment: After your edits the "lookbehind" part works for me with the exception of the `Select-String` variant where the `$db` is empty after evaluation.

Comment: @arco444 Nope. You can just use the file as the input for `select-string` there is no wrong way. Mileage could vary for larger files

Comment: @daniel.kahlenberg Did you change the file path? I noticed I had my test file in there.

Comment: file path is '.\cabal.sandbox.config' and it's there.

Comment: @daniel.kahlenberg What is your powershell version? I made an update that I think would help

Comment: `PSVersion                      2.0`

Comment: With `$db = (Select-String .\cabal.sandbox.config -Pattern '(?<=package-db: ).*').Matches.Value` `$db` is empty there.

Comment: @daniel.kahlenberg Check my small update I made a couple of minutes ago and tell me if that is different for you

Comment: I confirm the update works for my version of powershell.